# Cordova File Transfer error 1 Laravel

Tags: angularjs, cordova, laravel, ionic-framework, file-transfer

I'm working on an Ionic angular 1 app where I want to upload a picture to my laravel api server. However I'm getting error 1 (File not found?) and an laravel php error as error body back. I've followed multiple examples for uploading files this way, I keep getting this errors..

Angular Code:

```
     $scope.takePicture = function () {
              var options = {correctOrientation: true,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
                encodingType: 0,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI};
              getPicture(options);
            };

  var getPicture = function(options) {
          navigator.camera.getPicture(onCapturePhoto, onFail, options);
        };
        function onFail(message) {
          alert('Failed because: ' + message);
            }

 function onCapturePhoto(fileURI) {
              $scope.pictures.push(fileURI);
            }

  $scope.uploadPhoto = function () {
          var repairJobId = 1;
          for(var i=0; i<$scope.pictures.length;i++){
                repairJobService.uploadPhoto($scope.pictures[i],repairJobId);
          }
        };
```

So here I'm storing my pictures in an array because I want to display them in the app and make a queue for the upload process.

Angular Service

```
 function uploadPhoto(file,repairJobId) {
              var win = function (r) {
                console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
                console.log("Response = " + r.response);
                console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
              };

              var fail = function (error) {
                alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
                console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
                console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
                console.log("response code " + error.responseCode);
                console.log("error:  " + JSON.stringify(error));
              };

              // Destination URL
              var url = 'http://192.168.137.1/ac-laravel/public/api/photo/add';

              // File name only
              var filename = file.split("/").pop();
              console.log("filename:"+ filename);

              var headers={'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'};

              var options = new FileUploadOptions({
                fileKey: "photo",
                fileName: filename,
                chunkedMode: false,
                headers: headers,
                params : {'repair_job_id':repairJobId} // directory represents remote directory,  fileName represents final remote file name
              });


              var ft = new FileTransfer();
              console.log(file, encodeURI(url));
               ft.upload(file, encodeURI(url),win, fail, options, true);

        }
```

Laravel function :

```
 public function storeRepairJobPhotos2($request)
   {
       $destinationPath = 'uploads/';
       $newImageName='MyImage.jpg';
       $request::file('photo')->move($destinationPath,$newImageName);
   }
```

Errors I get : Cordova Error Code 1

Laravel error : ErrorException in Factory.php line 91:\n Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, null given, called in D:\PROGRAMS\wamp64\www\ac-laravel\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php

Anyone an idea? Maybe I can't just give the image URI to the upload process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error, reason was the rules function in my Request model wasn't giving an array back

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'photo'          => 'required| mimes: jpg,jpeg,png'
        ];
    }
```